# bash scripting: Best way to check multiple files for a value and return which files contain that value?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I am no bash expert, so right now I have like a 300 line script trying to accomplish something I feel can be done by an easier method that I just don't know about.

The script essentially checks multiple logs from different sources to figure out which hosts (by IP address) have certain services installed. I have these IP addresses condensed down into multiple files associated to each installed service.

How can I take these files, compare IPs in them, and have an output of which files each IP sits in?  Right now I have a ton of embedded while loops that are becoming very complicated and they are starting to get hard to update as I try to add more services.  Eventually I plan to have this output in a matrix where each unique IP has been found across all files and then have an "x" with each associated services installed per that IP.

I don't have a master list of IPs so I don't have an easy starting point for comparison :\ that makes looping more difficult.

Thanks guys.

Comment: Have you tried using grep?

Comment: Do you want a tool that takes an IP and gives you a list of files that contain that IP, or a tool that take a file name and gives a list of IPs in that file?

Comment: Edit your question to include some sample input and expected output.

Comment: Can you use Perl or Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to want an awk script like this (uses GNU awk for true multi-dimensional arrays):

```
$ cat tst.awk
{ hits[$0][ARGIND]++ }
END {
    OFS = "\t"
    printf "%s%s", "IP", OFS
    for (fileNr=1; fileNr<=ARGIND; fileNr++) {
        printf "%s%s", ARGV[fileNr], (fileNr<ARGIND?OFS:ORS)
    }
    for (ip in hits) {
        printf "%s:%s", ip, OFS
        for (fileNr=1; fileNr<=ARGIND; fileNr++) {
            printf "%s%s", (hits[ip][fileNr]?"X":""), (fileNr<ARGIND?OFS:ORS)
        }
    }
}
```

e.g.:

```
$ cat file1
a
b
c
$ 
$ cat file2
a
d
$ 
$ cat file3
a
b
d
e
$                            
$ gawk -f tst.awk file1 file2 file3
IP      file1   file2   file3
a:      X       X       X
b:      X               X
c:      X
d:              X       X
e:                      X
```

but until you edit your question to provide some sample input and expected output that's just a best guess.